# Maple, maximum value of a numeric function

Tags: function, numeric, maple

I am trying to compute the maximum value of the solution of a system with two ODEs using Maple. I have firstly solved the system itself:

```
> with(DEtools):with(plots):
> a1:=0.00875;a2:=0.075;b1:=7.5;b2:=2.5;d1:=0.0001;d2:=0.0001;g:=4*10^(-8);K1:=5000;K2:=2500;n:=2;m:=2;

> dsol:= dsolve({
diff( x(t), t ) = a1+b1*x(t)^n/(K1^n+x(t)^n)-g*x(t)*y(t)-d1*x(t), 
diff( y(t), t ) = a2+b2*x(t)^m/(K2^m+x(t)^m)-d2*y(t), 
x(0) = 1000, y(0) = 1000}, numeric, output = listprocedure);

> xt:= eval( x(t), dsol );
yt:= eval( y(t), dsol );


> X:=plot(xt(t),t=0..50000,color=blue,legend="x(t)"):
Y:=plot(yt(t),t=0..50000,color=green,legend="y(t)"):
> display([X,Y]);
```

I got the solutions of the system on xt and yt, but they are numeric solutions. Therefore, the function of Maple maximize() does not work:

```
> maximize(xt);
> maximize(xt(t),t=0..20000);
```

Is it possible to compute the maximum value of a numeric function with Maple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two curves `xt` and `yt` each have a single local maximum within your range of `t=0..50000`, so you can use the `Optimization` package for this in a straightforward way.

```
restart;
with(plots):
a1:=0.00875: a2:=0.075: b1:=7.5: b2:=2.5: d1:=0.0001:
d2:=0.0001: g:=4*10^(-8): K1:=5000: K2:=2500: n:=2: m:=2:
dsol:= dsolve({diff(x(t),t)=a1+b1*x(t)^n/(K1^n+x(t)^n)-g*x(t)*y(t)-d1*x(t),
               diff(y(t),t)=a2+b2*x(t)^m/(K2^m+x(t)^m)-d2*y(t),
               x(0)=1000, y(0)=1000}, numeric, output=listprocedure):
xt:= eval(x(t), dsol):
yt:= eval(y(t), dsol):
X:=plot(xt(t), t=0..50000, color=blue, legend="x(t)"):
Y:=plot(yt(t), t=0..50000, color=green, legend="y(t)"):
xmax:=Optimization:-Maximize(xt, 0..50000):
[xmax[2][1],xmax[1]];

               [9460.78688552799, 11193.0618953179]

ymax:=Optimization:-Maximize(yt, 0..50000):
[ymax[2][1],ymax[1]];

               [21471.8648785947, 19006.6009784691]

display( Y, pointplot([[ymax[2][1],ymax[1]]], symbolsize=20),
         X, pointplot([[xmax[2][1],xmax[1]]], symbolsize=20) );
```

[image]

For your simple example this works out pretty well.

If your `xt` or `yt` had many local maxima you could try calling `Maximize` with its `method=branchandbound` option.

And then there are other approaches where you could augment your DE system with new dependent variables like, say, `xd(t)=diff(x(t),t)` (along with appropriate ICs) and get dsolve/numeric itself to notice when that becomes zero (an extreme point) using the `events` facilities, or use `fsolve` on it.

Comment: Perfect! Very good explanation and really useful code!! Thank you very much!!